# Ioncube error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function [obfuscated]

Tags: php, function, obfuscation, deobfuscation, ioncube

I have a script that is encoded with IONCUBE 8.3.

And now , I have a Bad problem that I can't solve it.

the version of Loader is 4.6 on server (its lastest version)

But I see this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function [obfuscated]() in .... .
```

I have already obfuscated all the functions and classes and I can't let them unobfuscated !

So what should I do to solve this ?

I tried to solve it by cheking all function and setting on server .
But they are ok

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to be able to help. Are you getting this error locally or on a server? If the latter, can you replicate it locally?

Comment: @halfer i have tested both , but not working anywhere. What information u need? tell me i say it.

Comment: Have you read this? http://forum.ioncube.com/viewtopic.php?t=273. I found it using [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+Call+to+undefined+function+[obfuscated]).

Comment: @halfer i have searched alot. So, as the first link, what code should i test or use ? What changes should i apply ? i didn't understand what it say

Comment: Well, I've not used IonCube, but searching for the error seems like the best way forward. From that link, it seems that this error might result from not blacklisting an error handler - perhaps that needs to remain deobfuscated?

Comment: It's also worth a note that even encoded pages can be decoded with the use of xdebug and similar software. Ppersonally, I now do not see any reason to encode software

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have encoded the files yourself and that you have the source, a first step would be to disable line number obfuscation so that you can find the location of the failed function call. From that you can look at the source code and identify the function that cannot be found. It may be, for example, that the code is calling a function with a name that has not been obfuscated, and an exclusion list could then be used so as not to obfuscate calls to that particular function.